# CakePHP 3 email error - Unknown email configuration "default"

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to send mail in a CakePHP 3 application. The same configuration in another application is working fine, but not in this application.

My email transport config in the config/app file is given below:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'SMTP',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'xxxxxx',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

In my controller:

```
$email = new Email('default');
$email->from(['chgav007@gmail.com' => 'My Site'])
      ->emailFormat('html')
      ->to($emailAddRess)
      ->subject('About')
      ->send($msg);
```

I am getting this error:

> Unknown email configuration "default".

What should I do?

Comment: you could verify that the entry 'EmailTransport' exists in the app configuration: try execute this above those lines:
`var_dump(Configure::read('EmailTransport'));`

Comment: Yes I did check it using var_dump(Configure::read('EmailTransport'));   And it is returning "null"in both local as well on live server.  In that case, in localhost it is sending mail properly but not in the case of live server. It returning error msg like "Transport class "SMTP" not found."

Answer (score 0):

try className SMTP instead of default.

```
$email = new Email('SMTP');
        $email->from(['chgav007@gmail.com' => 'My Site'])
                ->emailFormat('html')
                ->to($emailAddRess)
                ->subject('About')
                ->send($msg);
```

Comment: lol ... got `Unknown email configuration "SMTP".`